# What alternative can I use instead of window[] for global variables

Tags: javascript, c#, html, typescript, vue.js

Currently, the existing code I have is using
`window['heatMapStartDate'] = "@Model.HeatMapStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`
and
`window['heatMapEndDate'] = "@Model.HeatMapEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

I would like to remove those because I am not able to check their references on the typescript file. I am searching for a way to use them on the .cs file instead of the .cshtml file. Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

**home.ts**

```
const myApp = new Vue({
    el: '#dashboard',
    data: {
        heatMapStartDate: (window as any).heatMapStartDate as string,
        heatMapEndDate: (window as any).heatMapEndDate as string,
    },
    methods: {
         ...
    },
});
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model JorgeApp.Pages.Dashboard.Home.IndexModel

<div id="dashboard">
    ...
</div>

<script>
    window['heatMapStartDate'] = "@Model.HeatMapStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")";
    window['heatMapEndDate'] = "@Model.HeatMapEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")";
</script>
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace JorgeApp.Pages.Dashboard.Home
{
    public class IndexModel : Models.PageModels.DashboardModel
    {
        ...

        public DateTime HeatMapStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime HeatMapEndDate { get; set; }

        ...

        public ActionResult OnGet()
        {  

            HeatMapEndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-1);
            HeatMapStartDate = HeatMapEndDate.AddDays(-7);

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this: "I am not able to check their references on the typescript file."?

Comment: When I'm on the .ts file, then I try to find all references of  ```(window as any).heatMapStartDate as string```, I don't get anything.

Comment: Use `data-` attributes on a commonly accessible HTML element. E.g., `data-heat-map-start-date="@Model.HeatMapStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"` Then in your element do whatever you do in Vue.js to access the element's attributes to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try browser **localstorage** to store data globally over specific domain or you can use browser **sessionstorage** to store data globally over specific session (a browser tab session).

`localstorage['heatMapStartDate'] = "@Model.HeatMapStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")";`

OR

`sessionStorage['heatMapStartDate'] = "@Model.HeatMapStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")";`

AND your can access these data by;

`data: { heatMapStartDate: localstorage['heatMapStartDate'] as string }`

OR

`data: { heatMapStartDate: sessionStorage['heatMapStartDate'] as string }`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare additional properties on the window object using a TypeScript declaration file (e.g. `global.d.ts`):

```
declare global {
    interface Window { 
        heatMapStartDate: string;
        heatMapEndDate: string;
    }
}
```

And then you can use them like this:

```
window.heatMapStartDate = "@Model.HeatMapStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")";
window.heatMapStartDate = "@Model.HeatMapEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")";
```